# Java Math Completing the square calculator

Tags: java, math, calculator, algebra

Hey im new to the whole programming scene im just a high schooler taking a java computer science course. Im trying to test out my abilities with what I know so far and to try understand stuff and practice. So im trying to make a couple math calculators for certain things. Im working on one to complete the square. So like (2 + 4x^2)^2 will come out to be (4  + 16x + 4x^2). My problem is that I cant get it to fully work, and the code is kinda klanky.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SquaringDoubles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //declaring
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //inputs
        System.out.println("Enter in the double with this format ( A + B )^2");

        System.out.print("A --> ");
        double A = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("B --> ");
        double B = input.nextInt();
        input.close();

        System.out.println("You're Equation: " + A + " + " + B + "x");

        //Math
        //A + C + B
        double A2 = Math.pow(A, 2);
        double B2 = Math.pow(B, 2);
        double C = 2 * (A * B);

        //final
        System.out.print("You answer: ");
        System.out.println(A2 + " + "+ C + "x" + " + "+ B2+ "x^2");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are doing good, just decide the degree of polynomial and coefficients of it while calculating. it's not that difficult. You need to pur proper System.out.println("") statements to avoid any confusion, in above code you need to update.

Comment: (2 + 4x^2)^2 is not equal to 4 + 16x + 4x^2

Comment: (2 + 4x)^2 is equal to 4.0 + 16.0x + 16.0x^2

Comment: which is the output of your program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting is the simplest general approach to get from one formula to an equivalent equation of form

```
Y(x) = A2 + B2x + C2(x)^2
```

As there are three variables(A2,B2,C2) we need three equations to solve the system.
To get those equations we can simply put three x of our choice and their calculated Y(x) into the form we want. And solve the system of equations.

So in essence we calculate Y(x) for three x of our choice and just stick them into the formula. One can take any (defined) value but some make life easier.

So

**X=0** is the first candidate as it eliminates everything with x and directly gives you A2.

```
Y(0)= C2*(0)^2+B2*(0)+A2 = A2
A2 = Y(0)
```

**x=1**:   you get

```
 Y(1)= C2*(1)^2+B2*(1)+A2 = C2+B2+A2
```

**x=-1**: you get

```
Y(-1)= C2*(-1)^2+B2*(-1)+A2= C2-B2+A2
```

Eliminating C2:

```
Y(-1)+B2-A2 = Y(1) -B2 -A2
-> 2*B2=Y(1)-Y(-1)
B2=(Y(1)-Y(-1))/2
```

Finaly calculate C2 by inserting into  C2+B2+A2=Y(1):

```
C2=Y(1) -B2 -A2
```

> So in General - for any given(valid) equation to get to the form A2+B2·x+C2·x²:
>
> - **A2 = Y(0)**
> - **B2=(Y(1)-Y(-1))/2**
> - **C2=Y(1) -B2 -A2 = (Y(1)+Y(-1))/2 - Y(0)**

In your example Y(1) = Y(-1) due to the square, so

```
Y(x) = (A + B * (x)^2)^2

Y(1) = (A + B * (1)^2)^2   =(A+B)^2  // x=1
Y(-1) = (A + B * (-1)^2)^2 =(A+B)^2  // x=-1
B2 =(Y(1)-Y(-1))/2 =0
```

And so

```
C2= Y(1) -A2 = (A+B)^2 - A2
```

> So for (A + B*(x)^2)^2:
>
> - **A2 = Y(0)  = A^2**
> - **B2=0**
> - **C2=Y(1) - Y(0) = (A+B)^2 - A2**

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //declaring
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //inputs
        System.out.println("Enter in the double with this format (A + B(x)^2)^2");

        System.out.print("A --> ");
        double A = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("B --> ");
        double B = input.nextInt();
        input.close();

        System.out.println("You're Equation: (" + A + " + " + B + "x^2)^2");

        //Math
        //A + C + B
        double A2 = Math.pow(A, 2);
        /**  old code:
         * 
        double B2 = Math.pow(B, 2);

        double C = 2 * (A * B);
        */     
        /** replacement : */
        //Y(1)=(A + B*(1)^2)^2 = (A+B)^2
        //Y(-1)=(A + B*(-1)^2)^2 = (A+B)^2
        //B2 = (Y(1)-Y(-1))/2 = ((A+B)^2 -(A+B)^2)/2 = 0
        double B2=0; // it is always 0 in this case
        //Y(1)=(A + B*(1)^2)^2 = (A+B)^2
        double C2=(A+B)*(A+B) - A2; //Y(1) -A2 
        //final
        System.out.print("You answer: ");
        System.out.println(A2 + " + " + B2 + "x" + " + " + C2 + "x^2");
    }
```

I added some comments, to show what is going on and how to do similar with other equation.